# Sql server query multiple pattern

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to match multiple patterns from a table.

I have five different names and query should fetch all records that have those name/string listed.

Regards,
 Nawab

Comment: Your question is not clear, perhaps add some details and some of your code so that anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where mycolumn in ('Name1','Name2','Name3')
```

If you are pattern matching with wildcards you need something like:

```
   SELECT * from mytable 
    WHERE mycolumn LIKE'%name1%' 
    OR mycolumn LIKE'%name2%' 
    -- add more OR conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from mytable where columnname like pattern
union 
Select * from mytable where columnname like pattern;
```

For matching the multiple pattern, simply replace the pattern

```
Select name,id from emp where name like 'A%'
union 
Select name,id from emp where name like 'Z%'
```